# Get original image size in Ren'py

Tags: python, image

I'm building a visual novel and in one scene, I want to have a couple of different images move from one position to another and change size as it moves.

My first position is called "doorway", my second is called "left2".
Here's the code:

```
init:
    $ doorway = Transform(xpos = 0.34, xanchor = 0, ypos = 0.6, yanchor = 1.0, size = (100, 400))
    $ left2 = Transform(xpos = 0.4, xanchor = 0.5)

label room1:
    show room1

    show laura normal at doorway
    show laura normal at left2 with move
    hide laura with dissolve

    show annie normal at doorway with dissolve
    show annie normal at left2 with move
```

My problem is that when I run this, both laura and annie stay at (100, 400) size. I'd like them both to revert to their original size once I move them.

I wondered whether I could write size = (0.5, 0.5) instead of (100, 400) to halve them (this would work for my purposes) and then put size = (1.0, 1.0) in the left2 Transform declaration to bring them back to full-size, but that didn't work at all and actually didn't show their images whatsoever.

Is there a way to do it with relative sizing, or another way entirely? Thanks :)